# How to search for strings using re.search() without considering spaces in the text being searched for the string?

Tags: python

I am creating a Python program to automate the loading of galleries onto a website. First, I have the following code:

```
import os

os.chdir("Obras 2023")

folder = list(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir()))
```

This imports the os package, changes the current directory to "Obras 2023," defines the variable "carpetas," and assigns it a list with the directories within the "Obras 2023" folder.

Then, I have the following code:

```
with open("galerias.php", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

import re

for folder in carpetas:
    
    if re.search(r"(?i)\b{}\b".format(folder), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        continue
    else:
        print("The folder", folder, "is not within the text of galerias.php")
```

I need the re.search to look for character strings (each value in the carpetas list) within the text of a .php file, regardless of the spaces between the characters in the text. For example, if the string "La Pastoriza 2023" is searched and the file contains the string "LaPastoriza&tit=2023 ," nothing should happen. If the string "Love" is searched and is not found in the file text, the string "The folder Love is not within the text of galerias.php" should be printed.

Comment: Even disregarding spaces, "La Pastoriza 2023" does not match "LaPastoriza&tit=2023", so it's unclear what you are really asking.

Comment: *'defines the variable "carpetas," '* - Eh? No it doesn't... It defines the variable `folder` though... Maybe that's a translation error?

Comment: It is a translation error, I didn´t know there was an spanish StackOveflw but anyway I would have to try how good it is

Comment: @Marto You can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want a `folder` name like `"La Pastoriza 2023"`
to be turned into a regex that search for three sequential words:
`"\bLa\b.*\bPastoriza\b.*\b2023\b"`.
This will skip over distractors like `"&tit="` and *still* match.

```
def _get_words(folder):
    for word in folder.split():
        if word.isalnum():  # forbid regex special characters
            yield rf"\b{word}\b"

for folder in carpetas:
    pattern = re.compile(".*".join(_get_words(folder)), re.I)
    if pattern.search(text):
        continue ...
```

I caution you that this turns user input into
a rather permissive regex.
If there is something in `text` which always
introduces each new record, incorporate that into the regex.

Having those `.*` subexpressions is not good.
If the set of distractors is known in advance,
it would be much better to pre-process `folder`
by stripping them out or converting them to blanks.

---

Prefer [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path)
over the os.path.* functions.
For example, pathlib offers convenient globbing.

Comment: *"forbid regex special characters"* - That's not what that does (e.g. `'_'.isalnum()` → `False`), but regardless, it'd be better to just [`re.escape(word)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), then you don't lose content from user input. Otherwise, this is great advice.